# How to rename thousands of directories, and remove last 9 characters starting with 'it' in Linux using shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rename, move

I need to change the name of a thousand directories and subdirectories, cutting the last 9 characters off the name. These final 9 characters start with "it".

example: 193-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo7 to 193-105kg-dal-brasile

I have tried the following command:

```bash
find /Users/myuser/Downloads/damod -type d -iname '*' mv "$i" "${i:50: -2}"
```

I use osx, I have Brew installed. I very much appreciate any help.

i'have seen the suggested case,  insted in article keep the last carachter with this formula (.{48}$), my case is not a duplicate
thanks

Comment: You say 9 characters but the example has 10 characters removed.

Comment: Is there any risk that directories named like `193-105kg-dal-brasile` already exist or that eg. `193-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo7` and `193-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo6` both exist?

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` with `sed` and `xargs`:

```
find "$test_dir" ! -path "$test_dir" -type d -print0 | sed -z 'p;s/.\{10\}$//' | xargs -0 -n 2 mv
```

For thousands of files, you may be able to utilize `xargs -P` switch to enable parallel processing. Example using up to 4 parallel processes:

```
find "$test_dir" ! -path "$test_dir" -type d -print0 | sed -z 'p;s/.\{10\}$//' | xargs -0 -n 2 -P 4 mv
```

-- OR --

Using `find` with bash process substitution to loop directories and rename them:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' d ; do 
    mv "$d" "${d::${#d}-10}"
done < <(find "$test_dir" ! -path "$test_dir" -type d -print0)
```

Note: OP indicates desire to remove trailing 9 characters but OP's example shows 10 characters removed (including final '-' in original example directory name).

---

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

test_dir=""

setup() {
    test_dir=$(mktemp -d -p .) 
    for i in {1..9} ; do mkdir "${test_dir}/19$i-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo$i" ; done
}

cleanup() {      
  rm -rf "$test_dir"
}

list_dirs() {
    while IFS= read -r -d '' d ; do 
        printf "%s\n" "$d"
    done < <(find "$test_dir" ! -path "$test_dir" -type d -print0) | sort
}

trap cleanup EXIT

setup
list_dirs

# while IFS= read -r -d '' d ; do 
#     mv "$d" "${d::${#d}-10}"
# done < <(find "$test_dir" ! -path "$test_dir" -type d -print0)

find "$test_dir" ! -path "$test_dir" -type d -print0 | sed -z 'p;s/.\{10\}$//' | xargs -0 -n 2 -P 4 mv

list_dirs
```

Output:

```
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/191-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo1
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/192-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo2
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/193-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo3
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/194-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo4
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/195-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo5
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/196-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo6
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/197-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo7
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/198-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo8
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/199-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo9
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/191-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/192-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/193-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/194-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/195-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/196-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/197-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/198-105kg-dal-brasile
./tmp.V0s210g0PM/199-105kg-dal-brasile
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash has variable substitution, which you can use:

```bash
for f in $(find ~/Downloads/damod -type d); do echo mv "$f" "${f/%-it*/}"; done
```

The command above does not actually rename. It merely displays the actions.
If the output looks good, then you can remove the "echo" part and have it should rename for real.

The `${f/%-it*/}` expression says *search for suffix (as denoted by the % sign) "-it*" and replace it with nothing (there is no text that follows the second forward slash).*

Comment: `${f/%-it???????}` seems safer if not prefiltering in find

Comment: Yes, @jhnc, that expression is safer.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use locate:

1 - Locate the directories:

```
locate "/directory"
```

2 - Use grep to search for lines ending with "it":

```
grep -E "/it[^/]{9}$"
```

3 - Read each directory:

```
while read -r dir;
```

4 - Get the new name of the directory by removing the last 9 characters:

```
n_name=$(echo "$dir" | sed -E 's/(.*)(it[^/]{9})$/\1/')
```

5 - Rename the directory:

```
mv "$dir" "$n_name"
```

exemple :

```
locate "/directory" | grep -E "/it[^/]{9}$" | while read -r dir; do n_name=$(echo "$dir" | sed -E 's/(.*)(it[^/]{9})$/\1/'); mv "$dir" "$n_name"; done
```

Script Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory_path="/directory"

locate "$directory_path" | grep -E "/it[^/]{9}$" | while read -r dir; do
    n_name=$(echo "$dir" | sed -E 's/(.*)(it[^/]{9})$/\1/')
    mv "$dir" "$n_name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew provides Perl [rename](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename):

```
top="/Users/myuser/Downloads/damod"

# check what would happen:
find "$top" -depth -type d -exec rename -n 's/-it.{7}$//' {} +

# actually run the command:
find "$top" -depth -type d -exec rename -v 's/-it.{7}$//' {} +
```

`rename` will complain if something with the new name already exists.

Using `-depth` means that both parts of a path like `193-105kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo7/13-15kg-dal-brasile-it8petfo8` will be renamed.